# Unable to see project in android studio downloaded from github

Tags: android, android-studio, github

https://github.com/caiolopes/Sliding-Tile-Puzzle I have downloaded the code from above link. When i open the project in android studio empty screen is seen. Here is the below image:

[image: android studio]

Comment: Plz click on left side project pannel

Comment: @DaminiMehra He already done that, as you see on the picture

Comment: switch from Android view to project view and modify the gradle files with sdk n build version with yours installed ones, then sync the project

Answer (score 0):

You have to clone the project from android studio or git bash...
In Android Studio, File > New > New Project from Version Control > GitHub
Enter your user and password from GitHub.
Enter the repo url and that's all.

Comment: what is repo url?

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart with Invalidate Caches/ Restart

[image]

And Try to Update your studio

> **Android 2.2 Preview 7**

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio22preview7available

Answer (score 0):

First, [Github](http://github.com/) is FREE( for public repo ) , try [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org/) (to get private repo), you can try it for free.If you are a developer, you should have an Github account.

Second, you can clone projects from Github from Android Studio.

```
VCS> Checkout from Version Control > Github, Android Studio will clone project and build project for you.
```

Third, the manual way, from Android Studio Menu.

```
File > Open > Your Project Location > Select build.gradle file.
```